# Datagrid inside datagrid - With filter based on parent datagrid value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm not sure if the title of this is descriptive enough, it's pretty hard to word.

What i have is:

Shipments
Containers
Packages

What i'm looking at doing is having a datagrid of *Shipments*, and each *Shipment* row would have an expander which would show a datagrid of *Containers*, and each *Container* row would have an expander which shows a datagrid of *Packages*.

Now i'm aware i use a `rowdetails.template` and have a datagrid inside of that, my issue comes in because the object *Shipments*, *Containers* and *Packages* are separate and are linked logically via an ID on the objects.

So obviously since the *Shipment* object doesn't have a list of *Containers* as a child to which i could bind, i'm unsure on how to get the result i'm looking for, or even if it would be possible to get that result with the setup i have currently.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

EDIT:

I'm wondering if it might be worth creating a new models for this `viewmodel`, that would contain a *Shipments* information and a list of *Container* models that contains a list of *Packages*. This way i could *databind* each child `datagrid` to the parent models list. (If that made sense)

Or would that seem to be going about it the wrong way?

Comment: _"each Shipment row "_ should be **cell** instead of **row** right ?

Comment: No, each shipment is a row in the datagrid.

Comment: ok and what contains your cells?

Comment: The cells contain information about the shipment, for example ShipmentID, ShipmentNo, Date Sailed, Ship etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, its difficult to apply a filter to a list of items in xaml, much easier to have a view model where each parent object has an ObservableCollection or CollectionView of child objects. You will need a AllShipmentsVM, ShipmentVM, ContainerVM and possibly a PackageVM.

If the data coming from a database, could you use EF to build your collection of child objects?

Otherwise, use a ICollectionView to display the items and set the filter for each parent viewmodel...

```
        foreach (var s in allShipments)
        {
            var svm = new ShipmentVM
            {
                Shipment = s,
                Containers = (new CollectionViewSource { Source = allContainerVMs }).View
            };
            svm.Containers.Filter = (o) => (o as ContainerVM).Container.ShipmentID == svm.Shipment.ShipmentID;
            allShipmentVMs.Add(svm);
        }
```

Comment: I think this would be the best way of going about this, because the data is access offsite the data is actually pulled from web services not the db itself. Thanks for the reply.